# How to scale a part of picture use opencv？

Tags: opencv

Can opencv scale a part of picture？

If opencv can not achieve it, are there other ways？

Original image:
[image]

Result image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you describe there is a modification on a [vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) image - an SVG, or some other vector image format. To do it with a [raster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) image, it's difficult, at least.

So, no, OpenCV will not help you, nor other image processing functions. The solution is to work with vectorial images - by example, you know you have a circle with given center, radius and color, and two intersecting lines - you modify their parameters and then plot them on a new image.

Comment: my mean is : How to scale a part of picture use opencv~
link Concave lens effect!

Comment: Now this is whole other story! Look on SO for fisheye effect, fisheye lenses, you'll find plenty of info!